# Starting Application Via Android Push Notification

Tags: android, database, push-notification

So I have found a way to send push notifications to Android in my case I am using [Parse](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android). Does Android however allow a developer to send a push notification that will instead launch an application on the users device? My usage case is in the event that the application crashed and for some weird reason did not restart I can check on the database side and see that the user hasn't transmitted any data in 6 hours and thus issue a push notification that would restart the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly! Just set the `Intent` to your application and `startActivity`

I had to use this for the same reason in my job!